# Typedef an enum value in C++

Tags: c++, typedef, enumerated-types

I have a base class that has an enum value that I am using in the derived class. The base class is a `Table<>` and the derived class is a `Matrix<>`. Now the enum value in `Table<>` is `TABLE_SIZE` which is used in the `Matrix<>` class. Since `TABLE_SIZE` does not make a lot of sense (it does a little!) in the matrix class, I thought I would typedef it to something more consistent with `Matrix<>` (`MATRIX_SIZE`).

```
typedef TABLE_SIZE MATRIX_SIZE;
```

That didn't work, which was a bit surprising. I am guessing I can't typedef the value because the enumeration is a type but not the values (not sure if that is a correct observation)?. So, now the question is, how-do-I/can-I accomplish the above?

**EDIT:** One thing I forgot to mention is that I do not want the Matrix class to increase in size (yes I realize it is a tiny increase and wouldn't matter for most people, in my case, it does).

Comment: Hint: **type** def a **value**?

Comment: @David: Yes, I realized that (which is why I wrote the `I am guessing` part) but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an enumeration:
enum { MATRIX_SIZE = TABLE_SIZE };

Comment: Will that not increase the size of my matrix class? (Yes I know it is a tiny increase, but an increase nonetheless)

Comment: @Samaursa: like my solution, this won't increase the `sizeof` the instances.

Comment: This will not increase the size of a class instance.

Comment: As far as I know, enums are like typedefs and static members - they take up size in the class, not the instances, so any impact would be on the size of the compiled/linked products. Would you agree? The effect should be minuscule for a single class, but might be more significant with heavy use of templates. I'm not positive, but I don't think derived classes would be affected.

Answer (score 6):

`typedef` is for types, not values. Use

```
static const size_t MATRIX_SIZE = TABLE_SIZE;
```

(Assuming `size_t` is the correct type here.)

Even better, just rename `TABLE_SIZE` to `SIZE` or `size`; since it's a member, it can hardly be confused with any of the other `size`s in your program.

Comment: I think I will go with renaming of the value. The const variable, although a good solution, will increase the size of the Matrix class (one of the reasons I wanted to typedef it in the first place).

Comment: @Samaursa: I forgot to put a `static` before `const`. That way, it doesn't increase the size at all.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I got this right, is this because each Matrix<> template, when filled out, will get its own static variable (not the class instantiation but the Matrix<> code that is generated for each case)?

Comment: @Samaursa: yes. That's what `static` does.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a different tack here.

> Since TABLE_SIZE does not make a lot of sense (it does a little!) in the matrix class,

Rhetorical question: If it doesn't make sense, why are you doing it? The answer is that there is some reason you need your Matrix to be the same size as the base Table. So why hide the fact? Be explicit. Don't obscure the fact the matrix size and table size are one and the same. Think about the poor future maintainer (probably you), who has to go plow through that extra level of indirection (probably with no comment as to why).

Not only should you be explicit, that you are intentionally making the matrix size the same as the underlying table size is a design decision that is worthy of a comment.

Always program as if the future maintainer is a homicidal maniac who knows where you live.

Comment: hmm, that is actually a very good point. I foresaw the same thing happening just on a different angle. Imagine me trying to find a bug and running into the declaration of this function and I see TABLE_SIZE and think "So that's why it is all messing up! Let me fix that!". Now I don't know about you, but when I am tired (and worse, I don't realize it), I will change it. In this case, it will most likely not break anything, just waste my time. An alias, although one level of indirection, is in this case, imo, worth the price. A good IDE will tell you right away without going into the header.

Comment: If the Matrix is sized with TABLE_SIZE and right there in the code is a comment that says why this particular size was used, are you going to chase that down as the source of your bug or think that, hmm, that bug might be elsewhere?

Comment: According to the author of `Clean Code` (and I agree with him), avoid comments to explain things whenever possible. Comments tend to be ignored (I used to be on the edge with that statement until I started working with production code. They really tend to be ignored.).

Comment: Agile programming has its place. For example, it's great for developing prototypes when you haven't the users and the developers are pretty much clueless about what the system is supposed to do / how it is supposed to do whatever it is supposed to do. One big problem with such prototypes: There is a strong urge by all to declare the prototype fait accompli. That is a BIG_MISTAKE. Agile programming, being a synonym for CMMI-Inf, does not mix well with the kind of work I do (once we figure out what the heck we're supposed to be doing, that is).

Comment: Upvote for consideration of future maintainers social tendencies.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is the keyword for declaring a *type alias*, but `TABLE_SIZE` is not a type.

You could use the preprocessor:

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE TABLE_SIZE
```

<sub>(Waiting for the unsubstantiated "macros are evil!" claims. Go on, I dare you.)</sub>

Comment: Too easy: **No**! do not use macros!

Comment: Yes, macros are evil. If client code tries to define a variable `MATRIX_SIZE` for some other purpose, it instead defines `TABLE_SIZE`. Try debugging that.

Comment: Macros have no scope. Since this would probably go in a header file, then any class that includes it would get that macro definition. This could break code.

Comment: If macros are so evil, why are both boost and the C++ template library so chock full of them? Yes, macros are things to avoid if possible. IMO, The code in question does something worse than using a macro: it uses TABLE_SIZE, which is not a macro. Using ALL_CAPS names for things that are not macros is asking for trouble.

Comment: @David: I use caps for any constant.

Comment: @Tom: That is a widely-used, but nowhere near universal, naming scheme. I don't like it; personal preference. There's that potential for colliding with macros for one, and ALL_CAPS names are just too much shouting for me. Example: STEFAN_BOLTZMANN_CONSTANT and SPEED_OF_LIGHT detract from the rest of equations where I need to use those constants, and there really aren't any viable alternative names. (sigma and c are non-descriptive and overloaded). My eyes just want to zoom right in on the screaming text. I only use ALL_CAPS for macros, and I only give macros ALL_CAPS names.

Comment: @David: That is personal preference. Start using Visual Assist and it doesn't matter any more whether they are in all caps or not, macros are coloured accordingly.

Comment: I don't like IDEs. I'll use one if forced to. Besides, what about the color blind, or the visually impaired? Those color-coded IDEs are about as anti-section 508 as a program can get.